# Regex - Capturing group to return null for a non matching string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

I am learning regex now. My requirement is simple. This is my regex.

```
([0-9]*)(\.)([0-9]*)
```

and my input is like this.

```
1.9
2.8
4.76
3
7.8
```

I just want to return only decimal portion. I am currently printing 3rd capturing group $3. Output is like this.

```
9
8
76
3
8
```

But my expected output is this.

```
9
8
76

8
```

Please tell me how to achieve this. Whenever the string is not matching my $3 returns entire string. I want it to return null or any other default value(like '0'). Is it possible to achieve this using lookarounds? If so, how?

Comment: No, the output is certainly different. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/23teqX/1). Please share the code, I think you print the input if Group 3 is empty.

Comment: Please use $3 in substitution. you will get my output

Comment: Why "substitution"? You want to *match*, not *substitute". **What is the tool/language/code behind this**?

Comment: Paxata is the tool. There is only regexp replace function in this tool.

Comment: Are you sure `REGEXP(@column@,"([0-9]*)(\\.)([0-9]*)","$3")` returns unwelcome data? Also, maybe [`REGEXP(@column@,"([0-9]+)(?:(\\.)([0-9]+))?","$3")`](https://regex101.com/r/jDrDZp/1) will work better for you (not sure if it complies with Paxata regex syntax though).

Answer (score 5):

The chosen answer is not actually a good answer since it just works in some cases, but not all.

The answer given makes regex looks for two different accepted patterns (separated by the "or" | character):

`(\d*)(\.)(\d+)` and `(^\d+$)()()`

The first pattern looks for:

1. Group 1: a number digit zero or more times `(\d*)`;
2. Group 2: a dot at least one time `(\.)`;
3. Group 3: a number one or more times `(\d+)`;

The second pattern looks for:

1. Group 1: a text that has only at least one number from begging to end, with no other characters;
2. Group 2 and 3: nothing;

The first problem with this approach is that you are requiring that the number has at least one number on the decimals in the fist pattern option, when it's the exact opposite of what you want. The second problem is that you are hard-coding an empty answer on the last two groups of the second option.

The correct way would be to capture and receive exactly what it is in each group, being the first group the integer value, the second group the dot and the third value the decimals.

You must think of each group:

1. Group 1: Numbers, so \d. Is `.1` an option, or it should only grab `0.1`? Both are options in the previous answer. If you want a null integer, then you should use `*` (zero or more occurrences). If you don't want a null integer, then use `+` (one of more occurrences).
2. Group 2: The dot. Since dot is a special character, we need to use the escape character like `\.`. The dot should be optional, right? So you should use the `?` character (zero or one occurrences).
3. Group 3 is like group 1.

So the correct answer should be: `(\d*)(\.?)(\d*)`
This simple answer will give you the integer in `$1`, the dot in `$2` and the decimals in `$3` and nothing when there's nothing.

So, in the examples

`$1` would give you:

```
1
2
4
3
7
```

`$2` would give you:

```
.
.
.

.
```

and `$3` would give you:

```
9
8
76

8
```

This would be a simpler way to read, understand and the regex wouldn't need to check each part of the string for two different patterns.

Comment: I upvoted your solution as it is better readable and conceptually clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this using following regex.

Regex: `(\d*)(\.)(\d+)|(^\d+$)()()`

Demo: [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oIpBT3/2)

This takes into account only two cases.

1. Numbers with decimal part are matched and returned in captured in group `$3`.
2. Numbers with no decimal part so zero width is captured in group `$3`.

**Note:** If there are more test cases please specify in question. I was not able to put this in comment due to low reputation.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! Thank you. For the last couple of hours, I have been tearing my hair out, trying to work out how to return nothing, if the group is not captured. Your solution to put an OR [|] condition into the regex is ingenious.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson: This was answered in 2016, am glad it's still useful in 2018. ☺

Comment: That’s the great thing about StackOverflow. I guess Regex solutions are timeless:)